# Get entered value from input textbox to button template via popup in POS payment screen in odoo 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo-10, point-of-sale

I am using **odoo v11**. I am working in POS module. In that I created button name "Check Number" in payment screen which is only visible if once selected any payment method which's journal type is "bank". On clicking of that button one popup is getting open. In that popup there is an input field where user enter check number as a input text and click on "Confirm" button and popup is closed.

I want to do that first check weather button has some value or not. If button contains no value then button name remain as it is and if user entered number in that input field then button value is chaged and now it is that entered value.

[image: On cliking on "**Check No**" this popup is open and I want whatever value enter in input field "**Check Number**" is shown on button value insted of "**Check No**"]

Now as I said on cliking on "**Check No**" this popup is open and I want whatever value enter in input field "**Check Number**" is shown on button value insted of "**Check No**"

Answer (score 0):

You can check `var ButtonDefaultVal=$("#buttonId").val(); if($("#buttonId").val()!=""){$("#buttonId").val(($("#textboxId").val());}else{$("#buttonId").val(ButtonDefaultVal);}`

Comment: I can not able to get value of input field in textbox because both are define in different screen

Comment: pop is bootstrap modal or is it jquery pop up?

Comment: It is POS popup